# Looking for specific website with science fiction writing prompts

Tags: story-identification

Some years ago I saw a website with some story ideas. The story ideas were shortly explained. I can only remember 3 of them but I am unable to find them.

1. Humans live like rats on alien ships
2. There are multiple societies which are surveilled and at the end it turns out that the ones who observe other civilizations are also observed
3. Something with an alien in the white house.

Comment: Do you know if the site was dedicated to just that?  If not, sites like Reddit often have sections for Writing prompts.  (https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/ , for example, is one of the better know and often cited ones.)

Comment: The one that always pops up in my search results is [660  Science Fiction Writing Prompts That Will Get You Writing at Warp Speed](https://www.servicescape.com/blog/660-science-fiction-writing-prompts-that-will-get-you-writing-at-warp-speed).

Comment: @K-H-W yes, it was dedicated

Comment: @DavidW it was a dedicated site and the story ideas were all own blog posts.